# Cheap Toffoli gates with phase errors

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction, gate-synthesis

[Here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9503016.pdf), a cheap verion of a Toffoli, up to a phase flip for $|101\rangle$, is given by

[image]

with $A=R_y(\pi/4)$. Are there similar versions of cheap implementation of general $C^nNOT$ gates?

I tried to just extend it the esay way, but found several unwanted off diagonal entries. My goal is a explicite $C^5NOT$.

So I came across this one for 4 qubits:

[image]

which I found [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.03273.pdf). Can anyone help me to build the circuit for 6 qubits out of the description?

And finally I found [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0504100v1.pdf) approach:
[image]
but the number of $CNOT$s feels like $2^5$ in my case, which is too high for my purpose.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9842/simpler-implementation-of-the-toffoli-gate-on-ibm-q-for-special-circumstances

Comment: @MartinVesely looks like the last approach I mentioned. So for a $C^5NOT$ with phase errors, I would expect 32 $CNOT$s and the angle of $R_y$ to be $\pi/32$ right?

Comment: Exactly, I will soon post QASM code I am just constructing on IBM Q.

Comment: I was wondering if there has been any new updates on this. I recently found a general circuit for Toffoli with phase errors that has polynomial complexity.

Comment: @MinhPham Can you provide a reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9842/simpler-implementation-of-the-toffoli-gate-on-ibm-q-for-special-circumstances) thread, below is a code implementing $C^5NOT$ up to a phase for output states $|q_0 q_1 q_2 q_3 q_4 1\rangle$, $q_i \in \{|0\rangle, |1\rangle\}$ (with expection of state $|111111\rangle$). For these states the phase is $\pi$, so returned computational basis state is multiplied by -1.

Concerning number of CNOTs and $R_y$ gates, I think it is not possible to decrease its number and it rises exponentially with increasing number of qubits.

```
OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";

qreg q[6];
creg c[6];

ry(pi/32) q[5];
cx q[4],q[5];
ry(-pi/32) q[5];
cx q[3],q[5];
ry(pi/32) q[5];
cx q[4],q[5];
ry(-pi/32) q[5];
cx q[2],q[5];
ry(pi/32) q[5];
cx q[4],q[5];
ry(-pi/32) q[5];
cx q[3],q[5];
ry(pi/32) q[5];
cx q[4],q[5];
ry(-pi/32) q[5];
cx q[1],q[5];
ry(pi/32) q[5];
cx q[4],q[5];
ry(-pi/32) q[5];
cx q[3],q[5];
ry(pi/32) q[5];
cx q[4],q[5];
ry(-pi/32) q[5];
cx q[2],q[5];
ry(pi/32) q[5];
cx q[4],q[5];
ry(-pi/32) q[5];
cx q[3],q[5];
ry(pi/32) q[5];
cx q[4],q[5];
ry(-pi/32) q[5];
cx q[0],q[5];
ry(pi/32) q[5];
cx q[4],q[5];
ry(-pi/32) q[5];
cx q[3],q[5];
ry(pi/32) q[5];
cx q[4],q[5];
ry(-pi/32) q[5];
cx q[2],q[5];
ry(pi/32) q[5];
cx q[4],q[5];
ry(-pi/32) q[5];
cx q[3],q[5];
ry(pi/32) q[5];
cx q[4],q[5];
ry(-pi/32) q[5];
cx q[1],q[5];
ry(pi/32) q[5];
cx q[4],q[5];
ry(-pi/32) q[5];
cx q[3],q[5];
ry(pi/32) q[5];
cx q[4],q[5];
ry(-pi/32) q[5];
cx q[2],q[5];
ry(pi/32) q[5];
cx q[4],q[5];
ry(-pi/32) q[5];
cx q[3],q[5];
ry(pi/32) q[5];
cx q[4],q[5];
ry(-pi/32) q[5];
cx q[0],q[5];
```

Comment: +1 thanks, but I'm still hoping for an improvement. At least for a while...

Comment: ok, I checked the decomposition of the Hamilton operator of the corresponding unitary $U=\exp(-i\pi H)$ and found only product operator of the form $\sigma_y$ on the target- and $1$ or $\sigma_z$ on the control qubits, which is what I expect for an optimal decomposition. Interesting...

Comment: I was wondering if there has been any new updates on this. I recently found a general circuit for Toffoli with phase errors that has polynomial complexity.