# Decompose Toffoli gate with minimum cost for IBM quantum computer

Tags: quantum-gate, gate-synthesis

The known decomposition of toffoli gate that can be used on IBM quantum computer is : 
[image: decompoition of toffoli]

I want to know any other Toffoli gate decompositions that can be used on IBM quantum computer and have a cost less than 15 gates

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. Do these threads answer your question: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9842/simpler-implementation-of-the-toffoli-gate-on-ibm-q-for-special-circumstances and https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9800/if-an-auxiliary-qubit-is-allowed-how-to-construct-toffoli-gate-in-easier-way

Comment: Just note that this implementation can be used on any gate-based universal quantum computer, not only on IBM Q.

Comment: I have checked these threads (before posting) . The second thread says no .
The first one gives a gate which they say "not a general toffoli"  so it is not preferable to depend on it in my research .
Is the gate in my post is the optimal decomposition till now ?
Thank you @MartinVesely

Comment: Yes, the circuit in your question is the optimal implementation of Toffoli gate.

Comment: Thank you @MartinVesely

Comment: Note that while it may be optimal for the fully-connected topology, if you need to remap it to a less connected topology (if you can't do all 3 CNOT positions), there are better solutions than remapping this circuit using SWAPs.